# How to get SSAS object name using ObjectID?

Tags: ssas, objectid

How to get SSAS object name for a given objectID in SSMS?

I have extended events trace, and for the "LockWaiting", there are entries like the following under TextData

```
<ObjectID>E434BE08-E49D-43D1-9DEB-EF6EF6217146</ObjectID>
```

So, I need to get the name of that object.